# Detect parent click on chrome extension contextMenu

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

How can I detect parent click on chrome contextMenu?

I can catch the click on last items in the hierarchy(`child`, `child2`) but I would like to also detect when user clicks `Parent`, `Parent 2`, `Grand Parent`, `Grand Parent2` and so on.

Or is it something not supported by the API?

[image: screenshot1]

Comment: Let us know how you build\create the context menus and how you handle the onClicked event.

Comment: There's no way.

Comment: What said by @wOxxOm is not properly correct.     


I asked you some line of code because the images are "not talking".
In fact, "parent 2", "parent3", "grand parent2" and "grand parent3" can be reached if they have no children (so they are also considered leaves of the tree or last objects in the hierarchy)

Comment: @Robbi "parent 2", "parent 3" will for sure have children, that's the challenge, otherwise I'm successfully catching click events on last items without children

Comment: you know, I have no power of clairvoyance... and the mother of fools is always pregnant. Anyway, read back you question and you're welcome.